# Asp.net/c# partial classes with same members and same parameters works in website project but not in web application project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I recently converted my website project to web application project following https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project/ guide.

After I compile I am getting...

> Type '_HR' already defines a member called 'Page_Load' with the same parameter types.

And there are others of same type.

This does not throw any error in website project though.

Here is the code for two different pages:

**HR.aspx.cs**

```
    public partial class _HR : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BuildMenu();
        }
        string menu = Request.QueryString["m"];
        if (menu == null) menu = MENU_FIND;
        string operation = GetMenuOperation(menu);
        if (AllowOperation(operation))
        {
            string control = GetOperationControl(operation);
            content_window.Controls.Add(Page.LoadControl("~/usercontrols/" + control + ".ascx"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Other.aspx.cs**

```
    public partial class _HR : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        content_window.Controls.Clear();
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BuildMenu();
        }
     }
}
```

Any help here would be great. Thank you

Comment: Both of your pages have the same class `_HR`. You need to have a unique class name for each page. Otherwise you're declaring a `Page_Load` function for `_HR`, and then trying to declare it *again* on other pages. If you change the class on the `.cs` page, make sure to update your `.aspx` page's `Inherit` property on the first line.

Comment: Thank you santi, But the question is that it works in website project but not in web application project.

Comment: An application compiles the entire namespace into one single DLL. A website runs each page individually and is essentially unaware that the other pages share a class.

Comment: This makes sense, what are the complications if I change the class names? They might have some kind of dependency.

Comment: Changing class names for the pages themselves in general shouldn't cause any issues. The standard structure of an ASP.Net application is that each page has its own class, and any shared classes are separate files.